# what's the best way to do my appendix?

Tags: appendices

I am a new latex user, I would be grateful if you could help me to do appendix in my thesis, in my code below I use this way to do my appendix but I need the best and easiest way to do appanix, as well as that How can I refer to (Appendix I) in (Copyright) chapter for example.
My code is :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{times} %Times new roman font
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Copyright}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\newpage

\chapter*{Appendixes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendixes}
\section*{Appendix I (Benchmark IEC microgrid data)}
\begin{itemize}
\item Utility: rated short-circuit MVA=1000, f=60 Hz, rated kV=120, $V_{base}$=120 kV.
\item Distributed Generations (DGs):
\begin{itemize}
\item DG1, DG3: synchronous generator with rated MVA=9, f=60Hz, rated kV=2.4, Inertia constant H=1.07 s, friction factor F=0.1 pu, Rs=0.0036 pu, $Xd$=1.56 pu, $Xd^\prime$=0.296 pu, $Xd^{\prime\prime}$=0.177 pu, $Xq$=1.06 pu, $Xq^{\prime\prime}$=0.177 pu, $Xl$=0.052 pu, $Td^\prime$=3.7 s, $Td^{\prime\prime}$=0.05 s, $Tq0^{\prime\prime}$=0.05 s.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the appendices with `\part*{Appendices}`, then issue `\appendix` to change the chapter numbering scheme. If you want the appendices with roman numbering you can use

```
\makeatletter
\def\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\makeatother
```

after `\appendix`. Then you start each appendix with `\chapter`, and add a `\label` to it. After than you can use `\ref` normally.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
% \usepackage{times} %Times new roman font
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Copyright}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test see Appendix~\ref{app:benchmark}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\newpage

\part*{Appendices}
\appendix
\makeatletter
\def\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\makeatother

\chapter{Benchmark IEC microgrid data}
\label{app:benchmark}

\begin{itemize}
\item Utility: rated short-circuit MVA=1000, f=60 Hz, rated kV=120, $V_{base}$=120 kV.
\item Distributed Generations (DGs):
\begin{itemize}
\item DG1, DG3: synchronous generator with rated MVA=9, f=60Hz, rated kV=2.4, Inertia constant H=1.07 s, friction factor F=0.1 pu, Rs=0.0036 pu, $Xd$=1.56 pu, $Xd^\prime$=0.296 pu, $Xd^{\prime\prime}$=0.177 pu, $Xq$=1.06 pu, $Xq^{\prime\prime}$=0.177 pu, $Xl$=0.052 pu, $Td^\prime$=3.7 s, $Td^{\prime\prime}$=0.05 s, $Tq0^{\prime\prime}$=0.05 s.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

Slightly off topic but important nonetheless: the `times` package has been for quite some time now. It was superseded by the `mathptmx` which is also obsolete and was superseded by the `newtx` bundle (`newtxtext` and `newtxmath`).